Keycloak "Welcome to Keycloak" Page (Keycloak 24.0.5)
When I access http://<ip-redacted>/auth/ or https://<ip-redacted>/auth/.
I cannot see the Welcome to Keycloak page.
I want to have a welcome page, without adding a custom welcome page. Is the Default Keycloak Welcome Page from JBOSS before no more? Is there no default Keycloak Welcome Page?

can you please get rid of /auth/ and try with https://

@user3509208 I am using http-relative = "/auth/".
The thing is when the link I mentioned is accessed it will redirect /auth/admin/master/console instead of the "Welcome to Keycloak page.".
